# List login sessions on a mac

Tags: c++, macos

I'm writing an application that runs as a system daemon (root session) for Mac OSX 10.6. As part of this application, I need to list all the active graphical login sessions.

There is an (undocumented, but public) function called `SessionGetInfo` which will give me more information about a session with a known session Id, but I need a function that tells me the active session Ids on the system.

The ultimate goal here is for the daemon application to launch an agent in each graphical user session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on Mac OSX 10.5+, according to [Technical Q&A QA1133: Determining console user login status](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1133/_index.html) you could use the `utmpx` API.

Some example code can be [UTXplorer](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/UTXplorer/Introduction/Intro.html).

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: deadlinks in 2020

Answer (score 0):

If you're not against invoking a shell command, there's always ps aux | grep SystemUIServer